# Run a java program using jvm.dll

Tags: java, c++, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embed Java into a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506329/embed-java-into-a-c-application)

Is it possible to write a c/c++ program to run a class/jar file using the jvm.dll library instead of using java or javaw? if yes, then how is it done?

Comment: What capability do your hope to gain by doing things this way?

Comment: I want to create a custom executable.

Comment: You can.  Simply have a look in JNI and read about how to embed a JVM in a C/C++ application.