# C++ GUI in Java SWT

Tags: java, c++, user-interface, swt

I developed a GUI application in C++. This GUI contains objects that belongs to external libraries for drawing.

What I need is to "import" this GUI into an other GUI made with Java (Eclipse). I mean I need to show this C++ GUI in a Java application.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want the entire application embedded in a Java application?

Comment: yes that's basically what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to launch the native application from Java. That doesn't sound like what you want to do, though.

The second easiest is make your native app a library and interact with it from Java using [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), or [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) (if you don't care about performance so much). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507024/375399). You'd redo your interface in Java (or perhaps there is a way to embed Win32 or whatever GUI framework in it, I don't know).

Also take a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

The hardest method would be embedding a JVM in your native application.