# C/C++ support (binding) of reporting tools?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, pentaho, birt

From the last few days, i am trying to figure out best reporting tools for my work. I have mongoDB database server and now i need to integrate it with reporting tool. For mongoDB i used the `C` binding so i am looking for a reporting tool in `C/C++`. I came across some great tools like `BIRT`, `Jaspersoft` and `Pentaho` but i didn't get clean answer whether they have support for `C/C++`. So my question is do they have `C/C++` binding or API?.

Also if you have some other tools recommendation for my work then please share that also.

Comment: Do you actually need C/C++ bindings directly to the report engine? There are generally http-based servers available so you can interact from any language. The reporting tools you've listed have direct integration so reports can be generated from a MongoDB data source. From an application point of view, you would just need to pass any parameters to the report engine (i.e. via http / restful API).

Comment: Also, asking for tool/library recommendations is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. A more appropriate site might be: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No, these tools don't have a C/C++ API.
However, as Stennie pointed out in the comment, this shouldn't really be necessary, as you can use them with a http API. If you really want to use integrate them tightly with a C/C++ program, consider embedding Java into your program and see [Embed Java into a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506329/embed-java-into-a-c-application).