# how to call jboss-modules.jar from C++ code using JVM/JNI

Tags: c++, jnienv, jboss-modules, jniwrapper, jboss-messaging

I have something like below, which is getting executed on java.exe.

```
"C:\Program Files\jre\bin\java.exe"  
-Djboss.home.dir="C:\Program Files\wildfly" -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dlogging.configuration=file:"C:\Program Files\wildfly\standalone\configuration\logging.properties" -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="C:\Program Files\wildfly\standalone\log\server.log" -Dprogram.name=jboss  
-Xmx3048m -Xms256m -classpath "C:\Program Files\jre\lib\tools.jar"; 
-jar "C:\Program Files\wildfly\jboss-modules.jar" 
-mp "C:\Program Files\wildfly\modules" org.jboss.as.standalone 
-c standalone-full.xml
 -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 
-Dlog.server.port=12141 -Dlog.server.ip=0.0.0.0
```

I want to call same as above , but instead of java.exe , I want to call it using C++ code.

I tried with JNI wrapper calls but not able to  do it.
one problem I am facing,

if u see main.class of jboss-modules.jar,its not taking "-c " option, and if I pass it as argument then it shows issue as invalid option,
Code example as below:

```
char* my_arg[] = {"-mp", "C:/\Program 
 Files/\wildfly/\modules","org.jboss.as.standalone","-c","standalone-full.xml"}; 
for( int i=0; i < 3; i++ ) 
{ str = psJNIEnv->NewStringUTF(my_arg[i] );
 psJNIEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(arr, i, str); 
} 
psJNIEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(jcJclass, jmMainMethod, arr);
```

Comment: Please edit your code example so that it doesn't need horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @rustyx: I dont want to call java.exe from c++, what I want to do is replace java.exe with my c++ code binary and do same operation which java.exe was doing

Comment: Then see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506329/embed-java-into-a-c-application

Comment: @rustyx: thanks for the link after tried with JVM/JNI wrapper one problem I am facing, if u see main.class of jboss-modules.jar, its not taking "-c standalone-full.xml" option, and if I pass it as argument then it shows issue as invalid option,Code example as below:    char*       my_arg[] = {"-mp", "C:/\Program Files/\wildfly/\modules","org.jboss.as.standalone","-c","standalone-full.xml"};   for( int i=0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
    str = psJNIEnv->NewStringUTF(my_arg[i] );
    psJNIEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(arr, i, str);
  }
psJNIEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(jcJclass, jmMainMethod, arr);